Problem installing Berkeleydb for python on windows
I'm trying to install berkleybd for python on windows but I get the following error:
pip install berkeleydb
Collecting berkeleydb
  Downloading berkeleydb-18.1.11.tar.gz (174 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]

      MS Windows is unsupported. I you need it, please let me know!

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I'm using python 3.13.0 and pip 24.3.1 installing on windows 11
I tried clearing the pip cache and I also tried directing pip to a local version of berkeleydb but neither helped.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.   I think MS Windows is unsupported. I you need it, please let me know! pretty much says what your issue is.  Try contacting the author/maintainer.

I didn't see anyone else running into this issue but it seems like it may be a recent change to berkeleydb.  Apparently in version 18.1.9 they removed support for windows.
